# web api + angular выбрать элемент и открыть окно его редактирования

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Связка ASP.Net webApi + Angular сейчас очень популярна, потому типовое решение для моего случая должно быть.
Мне нужно выбрать элемент таблицы и по нажатию кнопки перейти на окно редактирования.
Как создать таблицу, вывести и подсветить выбранный элемент я знаю. А вот как передать его - не особо. Если я правильно понял, необходимо добавить метод в HomeController, который переключается на нужное мне view. А вот как именно положить в это нужное мне view нужный мне id элемента, отредактировать его и отправить обратно - понимаю не совсем.
Кто-нибудь подскажет направление?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('component-list', {
        url: '/component-list',
        templateUrl: 'views/component-list.html',
        controller: 'ComponentListCtrl'
    })
    .state('component/id', {
        url: '^/component/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/component.html',
        controller: 'CompmonentCtrl'
    })
```